# Retrieving NULL from a json decode

Tags: php, curl

Ik got the following code to retrieve some json by API:

```
    public function get_json($jsonurl, $ttl = 3600) {
    $cache_file = $this->cache_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5($jsonurl);
    $function = __FUNCTION__;

    if (file_exists($cache_file) && filemtime($cache_file) < time() - $ttl) {
        unlink($cache_file);
    }

    if (!file_exists($cache_file)) {            
        file_put_contents($this->cache_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cache.log', $jsonurl . ': ' . $cache_file . "\n", FILE_APPEND); 
        try{
            $response = $this->fetchUrl($jsonurl);
        } catch(Exception $ex){
            return true;
        }

        file_put_contents($cache_file, $response);
    }
    elseif(file_exists($cache_file)){
        $response = file_get_contents($cache_file);
    }
    $json_output = json_decode($response, true);

    if(empty($json_output)){
        unlink($cache_file);
    }

    return $json_output;
}

private function fetchUrl($url) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if (!$response) {
        $exception = new Exception(curl_error($curl) ?: 'Empty response', curl_errno($curl));
        curl_close($curl);
        throw $exception;
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

Locally it works fine but on the live server i retrieve NULL. When i put the jsonurl in the browser it returns valid json. So maybe it has something to do with the fetchUrl function and the curl_setopt_array?

Please help me with this going crazy!

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($response);` before the `json_decode`? And are you sure it's not using the cache'd file and if it is that it has valid json in it?

Comment: Looks like sometimes i got strange html when i var_dump starting with:
<html><head><script type="text/javascript"><!--
function leastFactor(n) {
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n)) return NaN;

so this is not valid json but local it returns valid json

Comment: Also clearing the cache everytime on the live server but with no result

Comment: Strangely this is also before the json: string(1497) " Loading ... " string(56474) "